# Woocommerce Shipping Calculation Logic

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

### The plot:

I am working with a Dropshipping company that has an API for providing products, the shipping is calculated this way:

> Every product comes with a shipping size ( S,M,L ... ) and for each country this sizes have different fixed prices. I am saving this shipping size in a custom meta.

Example:

France

- Size M: 10$
- Size L: 15$

Spain

- Size M: 15$
- Size L: 20$

### The problem:

I cannot seem to figure out a way of implementing this into woocommerce. I see that I can setup a flat rate for each country but I cannot implement these different sizes.

If this is not possible with plain Woocommerce, I want to implement something myself with php or I am also open to any official/verified Add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out this on my own - so apparently I can make a shipping class for each of those sizes ( S, M, L ) and then I can setup Flat Rates by country and shipping class. This was very easy after all, no custom code required.

Answer (score 0):

insert by location rules with multiple locations you can place fees for each location. A different rate can be configured in woocommerce and can also be configured by postal code

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the plugin for handling all this stuff. I figured out this plugin maybe it can help you out. **Advanced Flat Rate Shipping Method WooCommerce**.

In this plugin you can create your own rules.